# syntax error when using 'ne' with a GUID in SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

I seem to be unable to use a GUID and the 'ne' operator when calling retrievemultiplerecords. The first portion of this query works fine where I lookup by ta_lead/Id...it's the second half that chokes where there is a value for thisGuid. Here's what I have tried and the results I get:

```
    options = "$select=ta_value&$filter=ta_lead/Id eq (guid'" + leadId + "') and ta_leadallocationId/Id ne (guid'" + thisGuid + "')";
```

This returns  Bad Request: No property 'Id' exists in type 'System.Guid'

```
    options = "$select=ta_value&$filter=ta_lead/Id eq (guid'" + leadId + "') and ta_leadallocationId ne (guid'" + thisGuid + "')";
```

This returns Bad Request: Unrecognized 'Edm.Guid' literal 'guid''' in '87.

```
    options = "$select=ta_value&$filter=ta_lead/Id eq (guid'" + leadId + "') and ta_leadallocationId ne ('" + thisGuid + "')";
```

This returns Bad Request: Operator 'ne' incompatible with operand types 'System.Guid' and 'System.String'

Any ideas out there??? Thx...clint

Comment: Can you post an example of the full URL being generated? You can use the `alert()` method in JavaScript to pop it on screen.

Comment: First one should work, try omit parenthesis: `options = "$select=ta_value&$filter=ta_lead/Id eq guid'" + leadId + "' and ta_leadallocationId/Id ne guid'" + thisGuid + "'";`